How to prune the rows of a Table
I have this Table which I am trying to transform by removing all the elements that are smaller than -5 and larger than 5 from the rows but not including the first element in each row (not sure that makes sense).
test = Table[Flatten[{i, Table[j, {j, -10, 10, 1}]}], {i, 1, 10}]

I would like to end up with what is equivalent to this:
Table[Flatten[{i, Table[j, {j, -5, 5, 1}]}], {i, 1, 10}]

Obviously the table is not that simple and it is not generated like this. It is imported from a file and I am trying to prune.
I tried this:
test[[All, 2 ;; Length[test[[1]]]]] = 
 Table[Select[test[[i, 2 ;; Length[test[[1]]]]], -5 <= # <= 5 &], {i, 
   1, Length[test]}]

But it gives the wrong result. I am sure I am on the right path I just can't see it!
Edit: here is a link to the actual data file.
Then thing is when I apply the solution proposed by @Syed I end up with an uneven Table. The rows do not have the same length anymore. I am trying to figure out what to do
The solution is good for the problem I asked! Thank you, the problem is my data is weirder than I thought.

test = Table[Flatten[{i, Table[j, {j, -10, 10, 1}]}], {i, 1, 10}];

Join[{First@#}, Select[Rest@#, -5 <= # <= 5 &]] & /@ test

(* or *)
Prepend[Select[Rest@#, -5 <= # <= 5 &], First@#] & /@ test


{{1, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{2, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{5, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{7, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{8, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{9, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{10, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}


UnitStep[x - a] numerically codes $1 \mapsto x >= a$ and $0 \mapsto x < a$.
UnitStep[b - x] numerically codes $1 \mapsto x <= b$ and $0 \mapsto x > b$.
Their product codes $1 \mapsto a <= x <= b$ and $0 \mapsto x < a \vee x > b$.
crit = UnitStep[test + 5] UnitStep[5 - test];
crit[[All, 1]] = 1;
Pick[test, crit, 1]

It's efficient on large datasets. On small ones, not so much.
test = Table[
   Flatten[{i, RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 100]}], {i, 1, 1000}];

a1 = Join[{First@#}, Select[Rest@#, -5 <= # <= 5 &]] & /@ 
    test; // AbsoluteTiming
a2 = Prepend[Select[Rest@#, -5 <= # <= 5 &], First@#] & /@ 
    test; // AbsoluteTiming
a3 = test // Module[{crit},
      crit = UnitStep[# + 5] UnitStep[5 - #];
      crit[[All, 1]] = 1;
      Pick[#, crit, 1]
      ] &; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.03099, Null}
{0.026923, Null}
{0.002548, Null}
*)

a1 == a2 == a3
(*  True  *)

Ref.:

Performance tuning in Mathematica? (point 2.3)
Does Mathematica have advanced indexing?


test = Table[Flatten[{i, Table[j, {j, -10, 10, 1}]}], {i, 1, 10}];
nw = NestWhile[Take[#, 2 ;; -2] &, #, Length[#] > 12 &] & /@ (Rest /@ 
     test);
MapIndexed[Prepend[#1, #2[[1]]] &, nw]

yields:
{{1, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0,
   1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {5, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {7, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {8, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {9, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5}, {10, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

